# How can eval command work in ansible playbook

Tags: python, ansible

I want to eval command via ansible playbook. Here's playbook.

```
 - name: enable ssh-agent
   command: eval $(ssh-agent)
```

I tried this playbook.

```
$ ansible-playbook -i hosts site.yml
```

But I got this error.

```
failed: [host] => {"cmd": "eval", "failed": true, "rc": 2}
msg: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

How eval command work in ansible playbook?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: eval is a shell function, not a function/binary. It also doesn't make much sense to set up ssh-agent for Ansible to use. What's the goal? To set it up for a user, or to do something in Ansible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`command` module expects an executable as parameter.

`eval $(ssh-agent)` is an expression that a unix `shell` can understand not ansible.

as tedder said I don't see why you want to setup ssh-agent, but if you do I recommend you give the `shell` module a try instead of `command`. Hope you've set `ssh-agent` to some appropriate value somehow.

```
 # Just for debugging.
 - name: enable ssh-agent
   shell: echo "ssh-agent = $(ssh-agent)"
 - name: enable ssh-agent
   shell: eval $(ssh-agent)
```

In this case ansible would pass the whole string to shell and shell would evaluate it.

Comment: This is useful for setting up a VM as a disposable dev environment.